# Are Ubuntu 1.0 and Ubuntu 4.04 real?

Tags: history-of-ubuntu

Many people say 4.10 was the first version of Ubuntu. However, a article i saw said that Ubuntu 4.10 was the first version **open to the public**, and that 4.04 was a development version not open to the public and 1.0 existed (and was quickly obsolete), too. Is this true?

### Notes:

- In your answer, you can also add why it wasn't true, or why it is true.
- This has nothing to do "What is the first version?". It's a question asking "Is 4.04 and 1.0 real?". This is not a duplicate.

Comment: do you have a link to the article that you mention?

Comment: @MatthiasDiener What article?

Comment: "a article i saw said that Ubuntu 4.10 was the first version open to the public, and that 4.04 was a development version" That is what Matthias is referring too.

Comment: Oh, i don't know. Maybe that "article" thing was just me. :)

Comment: How is it off-topic?

Comment: @markkirby It's not an duplicate.

Comment: I disagree @StarOS both questions ask `what is the first version of Ubuntu`, don't worrie about it, dupes don't get deleted, they just get linked together to compile the information, it won't affect your rep or anything. By every standard we judge duplicates here, this is a duplicate.

Comment: IMO it should read: "In your answer, you **should** also add ..." - without sources to back it up (unless the answerer *is* the authority), it wouldn't be much use.

Comment: @muru What i made means it's optional stuff like acpi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu) article about Ubuntu says the following:

> Ubuntu 4.10 (Warty Warthog), released on 20 October 2004, was
>   Canonical's first release of Ubuntu, building upon Debian, with plans
>   for a new release every six months and eighteen months of support
>   thereafter.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtqV0.png) Ubuntu 4.10's support ended on 30 April 2006.[10]
>   Ubuntu 4.10 was offered as a free download and, through Canonical's
>   ShipIt [11] service, was also mailed to users free of charge in CD
>   format.[12]

This seems to be the first release, as there is no 4.04 entry and Google does not find it, it would seem 4.10 is the first version, same for Ubuntu 1.0, I find no evidence of its existence.

Here is a comprehensive list of all versions of Ubuntu:

[image: Please do not edit this question so it becomes stupid]